# Should we delete **exact** duplicates that are duplicates down from word to word

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I'm talking about questions that are duplicates from word to word, not even reworded one bit.

For example:

[DLOGTIME complexity class and testing the length of the input string](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2011/dlogtime-complexity-class-and-testing-the-length-of-the-input-string)

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2018/dlogtime-complexity-class-and-testing-the-length-of-the-input-string

Answer (score 3):

In general, exact (word-for-word) duplicates should be deleted, yes. However this case is special.

2018 is a crossposted version from math.SE, migrated here, then closed and merged into 2011.

We should *not* delete those because it would break the migration for math.SE (the whole forwarding thing from link to the math.SE version). This is due to a bug. See the corresponding [meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53322/closed-then-merged-question-missing-merged-to-footer); hopefully this will be fixed soon.

Comment: User-created exact copies should be deleted, yes.